# Difference between tesseract 4 and tesseract 5

Tags: tesseract

What is the difference between Tesseract 4 and Tesseract 5?

I could only install tesseract 4.2 and I am worry about problems with the performance because this is not the last version.

Answer (score 2):

Mainly, Tesseract-OCR 5 has better performance (via "fast floats"), faster training for new OCR models, modernized C++ code, and an improved build process. There's also many other changes such as ability to read images from URLs, API changes, and bug fixes.

A full change log can be found here:
https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ReleaseNotes.html#v500

[Developer tweet describing changes](https://twitter.com/stjoweil/status/1465749018487701507?s=20)